# Exchange 2010 meeting invitation reply to address

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, calendar

My customer is asking about the following scenario and how to achieve it.

Exec Assistant creates a meeting in her bosses shared calendar on behalf of the boss and invites attendees.  They would like the responses to the invitation to be sent to the Exec Assistant and not the Boss.

How is this possible via Outlook 2010 or OWA?

Comment: The way I've always sent his is done is either by having the Executive Assistant have access to the executive's mailbox and/or calendar, and handle the replies that way, or to have the Executive Assistant set up the meeting with his/her account, and invite the executive, rather than the way your customer is doing it.  Dunno if there's a better way, but that's how I've seen it done when I've had the misfortune of not being able to avoid the executive-level... um, "people."

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the assistant send the invitation herself to everyone including the boss? All replies would go to her, and it would be on her boss's calendar, which I would presume she manages.